# Install Eclipse CDT on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to add the CDT to an existing Eclipse JDT installation.

I'm following the process below:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Help->Install New Software
3. I click the Add button
4. I enter CDT as name and the link `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno` as location for the repositories.  (btw the same error occurs if I try adding a local archive after downloading it from the eclipse site - [CDT master](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/juno/sr2/cdt-master-8.1.2.zip))
5. I select both CDT MAIN and CDT OPTIONAL features with a check-box to be installed and press next

In the next window I'm then prompted with the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: C/C++ Remote Launch
>   6.0.0.201302132326 (org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group 6.0.0.201302132326)   Missing requirement: C/C++ Remote Debug Launcher 2.4.0.201302132326 (org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote 2.4.0.201302132326) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.rse.ui [3.0.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be
>   found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: C/C++ Remote Launch 6.0.0.201302132326 (org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group 6.0.0.201302132326)
>       To: org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote [2.4.0.201302132326]

The weird thing is that if I just select the CDT MAIN features installation in the previous screen all goes fine and I am asked to accept the terms of license before installation actually takes place.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Any idea of what could solve the problem?
2. Do you believe it's important to install the CDT OPTIONAL features for standard programming and debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some googling I found out that the CDT for Eclipse depends on other specific Eclipse components, such as `bundle org.eclipse.rse.ui` (the one I'm missing and causing the error). A fresh installation of Eclipse may not yet include all of them, but they can be easily installed.

> Select Help > Install New Software... Click the link for Available
>   Software Sites. Ensure there is an update site named juno. If this is
>   not present, click Add... and enter
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno for the Location.

Now when going through the installation steps Eclipse should download and install the plugin's dependencies and everything works fine!

Comment: For any folks on Eclipse Neon (aka Eclipse 4.6), the update site for you is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/

Answer (score 5):

to solve the problem of installing eclipse with cdt c/c++ plugins, simply do the following at terminal:

```
apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt eclipse-jdt # don't include eclipse if you have it already
```

after a successful install, do the following at terminal; pls back-up workspace:

```
rm -rf ~/.eclipse  
rm -rf ~/workspace  
eclipse -clean &
```